# why android onlick in main activity not working

Tags: android

i build a new android app with empty activity
and added a onlick functionality just for testing but 
something seems to not working

the app runs on my LGg2 android devive
but it seems that the onclick listener does not response
when i click at the button(id:butt)

in debug mode i can step and see the listener is build
but i never come to the breakpoint
in the line where i set the text (.. t.setText(...

Can someone see , what im doing wrong ?

here is my Layout

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t"
        android:text="assdasd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here the mainactivity where i have the onclicklistener

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        public static View rootView;

        public static Button b;
        public static TextView t;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.butt);
        t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.t);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
            t.setText("lsdallsd");
            Log.d("asadssd","ssdasd");
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Comment: no i wrote this wrong shity code all by my self . thout inflate the view would be
necessary..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.butt);
t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.t);
```

use

```
b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating another view and adding click listener to the views there. However, the one that gets inflated by `setContentView()` never gets a listener attached. Change your code to:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
```

Comment: thx now i understand it 
i thought the inflate view is just parse the xml and store button ids
so that i then can get it with findbyviewid
..i thought my inflated view and the view in setContentView.. were the same
view 
...i new to android..)

Comment: Well...now you know. Just remember that whenever you are inflating any view, you also need to implement/set it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just not inflate the view, it's redundant.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        t.setText("lsdallsd");
        Log.d("asadssd","ssdasd");
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use layout inflater on an activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  TextView t;
    public  Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                t.setText("lsdallsd");
                Log.d("asadssd", "ssdasd");
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , i havent seen your answer , so i answered it myself accidently.
i should refresh the website next time..
im new to stackoverflow ..:)

Answer (score 0):

OK found the problem my self 
must be

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);
```

instead of

```
b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.butt);
```

but why i dont know
i thought inflate the layout 
and  would give the same result